# set browser locale in Internet Explorer programmatically

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, embedding

Is there a way to set the Internet Explorer locale (accepted languages) programmatically.
I have a small application which is embedding Internet Explorer and I would like to give the use the possibility to change the locale when clicking a simple button.

Is there a way besides tweaking registry and calling

SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_SETTINGCHANGE , 0, ...);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - when you embed IE (Actually MSHTML), you can change the registry entries used *for just that instance*. This is done by a callback to your [IDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753258.aspx)

Comment: This is the right fix. Anything else is a hack that will interfere with the proper operation of other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not -- IE pulls its settings directly from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but it might make more sense to use a rendering engine better suited to embedded such as webkit.

Comment: Currently the app is embedding gecko and Internet Explorer, webkit is planned ...